# TCL how to traverse and print all values for a variable having string and list

Tags: tcl

I have a 3rd party APIs that gives me below output:

```
puts [GetDesc $desc " "] #prints below data
#A_Name 9023212134(M) emp#121 M { 41 423 }
```

How can I access all the token of the value printed and the list **{ 41 423 }**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is a list of 5 items, where the last is a list of two elements. You extract elements in a list using `lindex`:

```
set var {A_Name 9023212134(M) emp#121 M { 41 423 }}; # A_Name 9023212134(M) emp#121 M { 41 423 }
lindex $var 0; # A_Name
lindex $var 4; # 41 423 (Note: leading and trailing spaces are preserved)
lindex $var 4 0; # 41
lindex $var 4 1; # 432
```

Comment: Thanks but can it coded up in a loop - there can be a scenario where one the indexes value might not be there - something like for each index print its value and if the value at index is a list then traverse the index

Comment: It's very hard in Tcl to answer "is this a list". `#A_Name` is a list of one element. `{ 41 423 }` can be described as an 8 character string.

Comment: If you know the 2 element list is the last element of the data, use `lindex $var end 0`

Comment: @Programmer Sorry, misread the question. Thought you only wanted the `{ 41 432 }` element. See Donal's answer for how to loop the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the values in the result with `foreach`:

```
foreach value [GetDesc $desc " "] {
    puts ">>> $value <<<"
}
```

This will print something like this (note the extra spaces with the last item; they're part of the value):

```
>>> A_Name <<<
>>> 9023212134(M) <<<
>>> emp#121 <<<
>>> M <<<
>>>  41 423  <<<
```

Another approach is to use `lassign` to put those values into variables:

```
lassign [GetDesc $desc " "] name code1 code2 code3 pair_of_values
```

Then you can work with `$pair_of_values` easily enough on its own.